# Problem with mysqli_num_rows() in OOP database connection

Tags: php, oop

I am still new to OOP and I want to create DB connection for user login and registration.
processLogin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'Database.php';

$userLog=new DB_torii();

$userLog->login();
```

Database class:

```
<?php
class DB_torii
{
    private $conn;
    private $user = "";
    private $password = "";
    private $sql;
    private $errCount = 0;
    private $sucess = false;

    public $passInput;
    public $error = [];
    public $passRewind;

    function __construct()
    {
        if (!$this->conn) {
            $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'zinuskerec');
            if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
                die();
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($_POST['username']) === true && isset($_POST['password']) === true) {
                $this->user = $_POST['username'];
                $this->passInput = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);

                return true;
            } else {
                $this->addError('no input info');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public function addError($Err)
    {
        array_push($this->error, $Err);
    }
    private function process($sql)
    {
        $sqlQuery = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $sqlQuery->execute();
        $result = $sqlQuery->get_result();
        return $result;
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE name='" . $this->user . "'";
        $result = $this->process($sql);
        $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if ($num_row == null) // should be 1
           
        {  
            $this->password = $row['password'];
            if ($this->password == $this->passInput) {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $this->user;
                header('Location: adminMain.php');
                $sucess = true;
            } else {
                $this->addError('wrong password');
                header('Location: adminLogin.php');
            }
        } else {
            $this->addError('Wrong username or username does not exists');
            header('Location: adminLogin.php');
        }
    }


    
}
```

I want to find particular row by username and then compare password with password input. The row_num should be equal to 1 (according to $sql SELECT )...However the code works fine when the condition is set to null. Do you have any opinions where the problem is or what files i should aslo share to be this more readable ?

Comment: There is any reason why do you don't use PHP PDO?

Comment: I want to try and learn basic approach to realy understand it first, and I am avoiding to be overhelmed by PDO features for now

Comment: IMHO I think you should start with PDO. I think mysqli will be deprecated in the future. After you learned PDO, you'll never go back to mysqli. I started years ago with `mysql_*`, now I know that it was a wrong decision

Comment: ok i will give it a try. The problem is that I am going through fullstack crash course , the deadline of projects is coming soon...I know that in those things i should not be in a hurry to learn things properly but  I would be glad for some help in this approach.

Comment: Please be warned that your `SELECT` query is widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Also, what's the reason for hasing a password in the constructor of your class? That looks pretty strange to me, especially as you use `return` there

Comment: Finally, is this a database class? Then why does it contain user checks and redirects? Any error you push to before redirecting to another page is empty afterwards, unless you use a session for this

Comment: ok thank you i will change that. where i should use hashing instead ?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your SELECT query fails.

First of all, your code is exposes to SQL Injection! Here you assume that the user input is safe to use as is in the query:

```
$this->user = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE name='" . $this->user . "'";
```

Always check for errors for every mysqli_* call (e.g. by using `mysqli_error`). I suggest to use also some `try...catch`. For example, here you assume that the query doesn't fail:

```
private function process($sql)
{
    $sqlQuery = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $sqlQuery->execute();
    $result = $sqlQuery->get_result();
    return $result;
}
```

After that, print the final query and run it manually to test it.

In the `__construct` method you shouldn't use the else statement because at the first running it only establish the connection to database but it does not perform the class fields initialization. So it should be something like this:

```
function __construct()
{
    if (!$this->conn) {
        $this->conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'zinuskerec');
        if ($this->conn->connect_error) {
            die();
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['username']) === true && isset($_POST['password']) === true) {
        $this->user = $_POST['username'];
        $this->passInput = hash('sha256', $_POST['password']);

        return true;
    } else {
        $this->addError('no input info');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Better is to handle variables storing outside `__construct`, because they come from user inputs.

Also, in order to maintain the user logged in, you should save the user status as logged in in `$_SESSION`, it isn't enough to save it in the class, because it will be reinitialized at every page loading.